# how to test form-data using mocha and super-test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to send form-data containing images(files) and some text data along side them in the same request while testing with mocha and supertest

[image]

what i have tried so far

```
describe('Testing', () => {
    describe('Get a successfull endpoint message', () => {
        it('User should receive a successful message', (done) => {
            supertest('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/')
                .post('/red-flags')
                .set('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
                .set('token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6ImJpaGlyZSIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6ImJvcmlzIiwiZW1haWwiOiJtdWhpcmVib3JpQHlhaG9vLmZyIiwicGhvbmVfbnVtYmVyIjoiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJHNJNEhReUVIeUtmUUNxV3lwd21rSk9XY2RVaFBSMFlVUGVrbVkwM3prY04xR1ROZk9PellpIiwiaXNfYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTU3NDk1MzM3Nn0.Qlmyo_ZNTdvkQvARFlUcfqZz-EOWK4bjV3gfC8zTxk0')                
                .attach('image', './sampleUploads/7bBYA.png')
                .field('thisBody', JSON.stringify({
                    "title": "this is the tittle",
                    "labels": "bro, we @   are, here, ",
                    "type": "red-flag",
                    "comment": "this is the comment about the red-flag",
                    "location": "-90,3"
                }))

                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(201);
                    res.should.be.a('object');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });

})
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there any error message?